# python code to send notification to Microsoft teams FROM AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Idea is to notify the message coming from cloud watch alarm to Microsoft teams. The messages is in the cloud watch alarm description.

Below is the JSON which is passed to lambda:

```
{   'Records': [{       'EventSource': 'aws:sns',       'EventVersion': '1.0',      'EventSubscriptionArn': '71d-4f70-927e-0a420040a154',       'Sns': {            'Type': 'Notification',             'MessageId': '152c308c--bca8-67281c9c3c36',',           'Subject': 'ALARM: "StoreException-" in ()',            'Message': '{"AlarmName":"StoreException-WAS102","AlarmDescription":"StoreClosedException-in-1.1.1.1","AWSAccountId":"xxxxx","NewStateValue":"ALARM"}}
```

Below is my python lambda code:

```
    import urllib3 
    import json
    http = urllib3.PoolManager() 
    def lambda_handler(event, context): 
        print(event)
        message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
        alarm_name = message['AlarmName']
        app_name = message['AlarmDescription']
        msg = {
       
            "text": app_name
        }
        encoded_msg = json.dumps(msg).encode('utf-8')
        resp = http.request('POST',url, body=encoded_msg)
```

But i am getting error as below:

```
> string indices must be integers: TypeError Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 15, in
> lambda_handler
>     "text": app_name TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I think i am getting the issue while using the dict. But not sure how to make it work. Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Your JSON has multiple issues - try an online validator to see.  Is that the real data passed?

Comment: Yes, this is the json passed I have removed some part of json as it has personal data.. but overall structure is this. The iteration which I am doing is correct. alarm_name = message['AlarmName']
    app_name = message['AlarmDescription'] when I write a print(app_name) I was able to get the alarm description value. But when the json is triggered by sns I am getting the string indices error